# Magento - change email in forgotpassword before check it

Tags: magento, events, forgot-password

In forgot password form, i need to get the email and change it before magento check it.

Why?, beacuse i need to change a customer personal number like 9834592845 to their email store in database (bla@ble.bli)

i work with the event:
controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_forgotpassword

but i can't get the email, i tried

```
$username = $observer->getRequest()->getPost('email');
$username = $observer->getRequest()->getPost();
$postData = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
$username = $observer->getData('email');
$username = $observer->getEmail();
$username = $_POST;
$username = $_POST['login']['username'];
$username = $_POST['login']['email'];
Mage::log($username);
```

and more, but nothing.

What i'm doing wrong.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: try Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams(); rather than putting it in log you can dump and die it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `customer_save_before` Observer in that you can write your own code

**Example:**

```
public function detectPwdChange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $event              = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer           = $event->getCustomer();
    $postData           = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();

    if($customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer && !$customer->isObjectNew()) {

        if( $postData['change_password'] == 1 && $postData['current_password'] != $postData['password'] ) {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's work, beacuse i don't try to save a customer and i can't get the customer ($event->getCustomer();) beacuse there's nobody login... but i tried anyway and... don't work

Comment: when you try to forgot password that means change in customer database. I should be call. Please try.